# Error: `position` must be either a string or a Position object, not an S3 object with class labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, data-visualization

I've made a simple [barplot](/questions/tagged/barplot), with the following code:

```
ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(y = Percentage, x = Medicalposition, fill = DLTIrecognized), 
                        data= DLTIrecognized_long, stat="identity")
```

But when I add the following code to the first to simply ameliorate the lay-out, I receive an error:

```
ggtitle ("title")) + theme(legend.position ="bottom", legend.direction = 
"horizontal", legend.title = element_blank()))
```

> Error: `position` must be either a string or a Position object, not an S3 object with class labels'

Can you please suggest how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: At the first look everything seems fine with your code. Therefore: Could you provide more information about your dataset? Otherwise it's quite hard to replicate the error and figure out a solution for your problem. Simply type dput(NAME_OF_YOUR_DATASET) into the console and paste the output as code into your question. As your dataset is probably large, it is best to give just a snippet of your data, e.g. for the first 20 rows dput(NAME_OF_YOUR_DATASET[1:20, ]) will do the job.